# scala: missing parameter type for expanded function: the argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I am new to scala and I have no idea at all what's wrong with my code:

I have some `Future` which may throw exception:

```
var clean: Future[Boolean];
```

However, when I try to map

```
clean.map( b => {
  case true => Ok("success")
  case false => Ok("failed")
}).recover {
  case t => Ok("error: " + t)
}
```

I get compile error specified in the title.. I totally have no idea where and/which part of my code exactly causes it.. I have googled but it is so difficult to find any clue because scala syntax is so flexible thus so many variations in the internet but the error I get is quite misleading...

Any help will be very appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are passing to `.map` as written is supposed to accept a boolean argument `b`, and return another function (the stuff in curly braces). The compiler cannot guess the type of that inner function, so it complains about the parameter type not being known.

That's actually a good thing, because it's not what you really wanted to write at all.

Just remove the whole `(b => ...)` business:

```
clean.map { 
  case true => Ok("success")
  case false => Ok("failed") 
}.recover { 
  case t => Ok("error: " + t)
}
```

Also, make `clean` `val` rather than `var`. Mutable variables aren't a good idea. 99% of time, writing code in scala, you should not need them, so, I'd recommend that you just pretend that `var` keyword doesn't exist at all for now, until you learn the language well enough to be able to identify that 1% of cases where mutable state is actually needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extra advice! Scala's loose syntax and flexibility has gotten a hang of me, I'll heed this advice.. Btw, Is there a way to let scala 'know' clearly the type of the inner function? I tried 'b: Boolean' or '(b: Boolean => Future[Response])' all to no avail. It is difficult to grasp "to fix 'missing some information' errors" by removing more information from it...

Comment: You don't understand. You are not "fixing missing by removing information", you are changing the meaning of what's written entirely. `b` has nothing to do with the inner function (and its type is actually very well known). There TWO functions in your code: one that you pass to `map` takes `b` as a parameter and returns ANOTHER function, it's this second one whose type is unknown. Something like this `.map { b => { x: Boolean => ... })` would "fix" it, but, like I said, this is not at all what you want - you'd just end up with a `Future` of a `function`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you intended:

```
clean.map( b => b match {
 case true => Ok("success")
 case false => Ok("failed")
}).recover {
 case t => Ok("error: " + t)
}
```